# How to insert a particular column data into a table in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want the first column of the data which is present in a text file delimited by space. Is there any possible way to retrieve the column without including the whole text file as a table and filtering from that table?

Comment: If you are loading data from the command line, then the `--ignore_unknown_values` option (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv) should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command line

```
bq --location=US load \
--source_format=CSV \
--field_delimiter=" " \
--ignore_unknown_values \
<PROJECT_ID>:<DATASET>.<TABLE_NAME> \
./data.txt \
name:STRING
```

You can change the file name, and the location. It's mandatory to set the schema in the command line to skip the other column in the autodetect mechanism.